# Why is sk-video not working even after declaring the ffmpeg path

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, video, storage

I want to get a video in a multi dimensional matrix form

I tried to do it with this piece of code

```
import skvideo.io

video_loc = "F:\\PROGRAMMS\\output.mp4"

videodata = skvideo.io.vread(video_loc)

print(videodata.shape)
```

it gave me this error message

> AssertionError: Cannot find installation of real FFmpeg (which comes with ffprobe).

then i tried another method

```
import skvideo

video_loc = "F:\\PROGRAMMS\\output.mp4"

skvideo.setFFmpegPath(
"C:\\Users\\*USER*\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\skvideo\\io"
)
import skvideo.io

videodata = skvideo.io.vread(video_loc)

print(videodata.shape)
```

but it also gave me the same error message

Then I installed ffmpeg but it still didnt work

Comment: The folder `site-packages\\skvideo\\io` contains Python files `ffmpeg.py` and `ffprobe.py`, but skvideo is looking for `ffmpeg.exe` and `ffprobe.exe`. In Windows OS there is no installer for FFmpeg. You may download the latest stable release 
[ffmpeg-release-full.7z](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds). You may follow the [instructions](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows) for installing FFmpeg on Windows.

Comment: On a related note, skvideo hasn't been updated since 2020. If you are starting a new project, it could be worthwhile to switch to something that is actively maintained like ImageIO, PyAV, or moviepy.